# Create new list as List<List<Integer>> in Java

Tags: java

I have a nested `List<List<Integer>>` and `Integer[] marks`

When I am sending the request from Postman like this :

```
"numsList" : [
    [1, 0],
    [2, 2],
    [2, 3]
  ]
```

everything is working fine. The request is getting mapped as `numsList=[[1, 0], [2, 2], [2, 3]]`

But when I am trying to write a junit, I am unable to create the request object in this format.

I am doing like this : `var numsList = List.of(List.of(1,0,2,3,2,2));` and it is in the incorrect format.

Need some help to correct this.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and be more clear about the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List.of(List.of(1,0,2,3,2,2))` is `[[1,0,2,3,2,2]]`.

You probably need `List.of(List.of(1,0), List.of(2,3), List.of(2,2))`, which is `[[1,0], [2,3], [2,2]]`.